# Beaglebone Black: RTC DS1307/DS1338 gives error in Android at bootup

Tags: android, android-source, i2c, beagleboneblack, real-time-clock

I am using the TI-Android-JB-4.2.2-DevKit-4.1.1 to build an Android for Beaglebone Black which works perfectly well. I try to use the RTC-Cape (http://elinux.org/CircuitCo:RTC_Cape). With the "onboard" Angström on the BBB I was able to set and read the RTC manually, therefore I assume that the hardware is ok.

To put the RTC in operation with Android, I added in the file `kernel/arch/arm/mach-omap2/board-am335xevm.c` in the struct

```
static struct i2c_board_info __initdata am335x_i2c0_boardinfo[]
```

at the end

```
{
    I2C_BOARD_INFO("ds1338", 0x68),
},
```

In `kernel/arch/arm/configs/am335x_evm_android_defconfig` I activated the `CONFIG_RTC_DRV_DS1307` (`CONFIG_RTC_DRV_DS1307=y`) and deactivated the `CONFIG_RTC_DRV_OMAP`.

At bootup it says

```
<4>[    1.880767] rtc-ds1307: probe of 1-0068 failed with error -5
<6>[    1.886779] i2c /dev entries driver
```

and

```
<3>[    2.306884] drivers/rtc/hctosys.c: unable to open rtc device (rtc0)
```

I tried to adapt the changes from this Beaglebone/Linux mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/beagleboard/DegreEdtI-Q/ZEdFLNnuTvMJ.

I am new to Android/Linux kernel configuration. How do I have to include and configure the RTC in the kernel properly that it is usable at bootup?

Regards

Matthias

**Update**

It turns out the DS1338 on the Beaglebone Balck Cape is in fact connected to 17 and 18 on P9, which is I2C1 or i2c-2 on Android. This bus is deactivated by default in Android. As a short workaround I cut the printed curcuit paths and wired it to 19 and 20 on P9 (I2C2 oder i2c-3).

Then I moved the `I2C_BOARD_INFO` block to

```
static struct i2c_board_info am335x_i2c2_boardinfo[]
```

The compiled kernel now reads the time from the RTC at bootup.

Thanks very much for the hint, user3926077.

A proper solution would be to activate the i2c-2 in the Android kernel and put the `I2C-BOARD_INFO` block in `static struct i2c_board_info am335x_i2c1_boardinfo[]`. Unfortunately i do not know how to achieve this at the moment and we need the RTC only for debugging, so the soldering solution works for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

static struct i2c_board_info __initdata am335x_i2c0_boardinfo[] is accessing the internal i2c bus /dev/i2c-1 but you will be plugging the rtc into 19 and 20 on p9 which is /dev/i2c-3